# How to catch Authentication Failure exception using XLWings?

Tags: python, excel, powerquery, xlwings

I am using below python code to Refresh the data on an Excel sheet which is using Power Query to fetch data from external source.

```
import xlwings as xw

app = xw.App()

wb = xw.Book('pathToFile')
wb.api.RefreshAll()
```

Sometimes we have authentication issues with external server. While manually refreshing from Excel, the Authentication Failure message is shown but when refresh the sheet from Python, I am unable to catch this exception.

Is there a way to catch Excel exceptions when using XLWings ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the details of xlwings, but given how bad Power Query is about telling Excel what it's doing, I wouldn't expect there to be anything simple. Power Query is perfectly capable of telling itself what it's doing though. You could make a simple query like this:

```
let
    Source = try YourQuery otherwise "ERROR",
    ErrorCheck = if Source = "ERROR" then "Failed" else "Success"
in
    ErrorCheck
```

Which will return a Success/Fail notification to a table in Excel that you can check. I only tested this by generically forcing a test query to fail, but I think an authentication error should trigger this as well. There are ways you can return specific details on errors in PQ as well, but I don't know if that's necessary for what you want to accomplish here.